# Weird behavior of JavaScript (With jQuery) 'scrollTop' on Android WebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, android-webview, scrolltop

I have an HTML file with an element inside it with `id="start_section"`.
I want that when the page loads it will scroll down to this element so i added the following scrip:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    // scroll 20px above this div
    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: (jQuery('#start_section').offset().top)-20 }, 800);
});
```

Now, it's working just perfect on the first time the page is loaded.

**But**, As soon as the Activity is recreated for some reason, like orientation change, something weird happens: The page is reloaded, and then instead of scrolling down to the specific element, it is scrolling all the way to the bottom of the page.

I tried to disable the cache but it didn't help.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to just use **`"jQuery('body')"`** instead of `"jQuery('html, body')"`